# OpenGL SOIL error

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a university project and it requires us to load up a cube model, texture it and do some other stuff with it.

We have been provided with a basic framework that uses SOIL to load up textures into OpenGL.

However, when I call the function:

```
SOIL_load_OGL_texture("Barren Reds.JPG", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS);
```

I get the following error:

```
OpenGL Debug Output: Source(OpenGL), Type(Error), Priority(High), Error has been generated. GL error GL_INVALID_ENUM in GetString: (ID: 491340553) Generic error
OpenGL Debug Output: Source(OpenGL), Type(Error), Priority(High), Error has been generated. GL error GL_INVALID_ENUM in TexParameteri: (ID: 2102148481) Generic error
OpenGL Debug Output: Source(OpenGL), Type(Error), Priority(High), Error has been generated. GL error GL_INVALID_ENUM in TexParameteri: (ID: 2102148481) Generic error
```

The thing is, I have another framework that uses SOIL too and when I run the same function with the same texture, it works fine. So I figured my SOIL build is not good, so I copied the working SOIL build to my project and still the same error.

I get these 3 lines of error whenever I call the function, so if I call it to create 3 textures I get it 3 times.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  No way to tell if you're requesting a Core context or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Core context be aware that SOIL's `query_tex_rectangle_capability()` unconditionally calls `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` (`GL_EXTENSIONS` is not a valid argument for `glGetString()` in Core contexts and will generate a `GL_INVALID_ENUM`) instead of using `glGetStringi()` to iterate over extension strings.

Your options are:

- Fix [SOIL](https://youtu.be/Eg6NIxS7jpM?t=241), or
- Use [`stb_image.h`](https://github.com/nothings/stb) directly and handle texture upload yourself, or
- Use a Compatibility context (where `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` is still valid usage)

Comment: +1 This is likely the answer. I recall having similar issues with soil months ago inside a core context, actually debugged SOIL and saw it was calling `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`. I ended up using stb_image and rolling my own image class.

Comment: Yeah it seems it is calling glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) which caused the error since I'm using a Core context. I decided to ignore the error for now since I can still use the textures despite it and I will be using stb_image.h to load up the textures myself. Thank you.